# "street, opposite the center"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, interpretation, paraphrasing

I read the following from a TOEIC book:

“Q. The convention center is located on Market Street, directly ________ Glenview Shopping Center.

[A] opposite
[B] among
[C] apart
[D] nearby

Answer: [A] opposite” ((ETS TOEIC Gichool Jonghabsuh [Publisher: YBM]))

I know A is the answer, but I want to know which interpretation is correct between these two:

Interpretation A: The convention center is located on Market Street, and **the CENTER is directly opposite Glenview Shopping Center.**

Interpretation B: The convention center is located on Market Street, and **the STREET is directly opposite Glenview Shopping Center.**

According to the book’s translation, Interpretation B is correct, but I don’t think so.
What do you think?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interpretation B is syntactically possible, but it's "perverse" (no native speaker would expect it). The implication of the utterance is that BOTH the convention center AND Glenview Shopping Center are on Market Street. Throw your translation out, since it's obviously not a reliable source.

Comment: Incidentally, "Gichool Jonghabsuh" is a "Googlewack". The ***only*** result returned by googling it is this very ELL question!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, FumbleFingers.

Answer (score 5):

It should be your interpretation, A.

> The convention center is located on Market Street, and the CENTER is directly opposite Glenview Shopping Center.

We can say a centre is directly opposite another centre.  In this case, the two centres are on opposite sides of the street.

We do not say a street is directly opposite a centre.
How do we align a street to consider it opposite a centre?

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. 